# Is there a limit on the number of workspaces that can be created in Terraform Enterprise?

Tags: terraform, terraform-enterprise

Does Terraform Enterprise have a limit of workspaces that can be created within it? If yes, how many?

Answer (score 2):

Terraform Enterprise is licensed based on number of workspaces. Therefore, a high number of workspaces would result in high licensing costs, which would probably limit you before a technical limitation in maximum number of workspaces.